# Sql Server 2008 - Erro: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eu estava usando o sql server 2005, após fazer a atualização, todos os bancos de dados não permite a visualização das tabelas no modo Design, e não deixa criar tabelas novas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei fazer a criação de uma tabela de modo visual é me gerou este erro, alguém sabe como resolver? Agradeço.

```html
===================================

Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. (SQLEditors)

------------------------------
Local do Programa:

   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.CreateDesigner()
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.Open()
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc, String fileName)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)
```

Comment: Parece ser um bug! Qual o nome da tabela que você tentou criar? Informe qual a versão (de forma completa SP, etc) do SQL.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - `NullPointerException` do C#. Reiniciando o programa não resolve?

Comment: Adicionei mais informações!